# Surjective homomorphism of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

In ii) I understand why det is a homomorphism but in the surjective part I cna't get the gist of what is going on. 
In iii) i'm rather lost as the solution isn't particularly expansive. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: For iii), you just need to show that for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ you can find some invertible transform $T$ such that $\det T = \lambda$. The idea is to just take the $T$ whose matrix representation is a diagonal matrix with entries $(\lambda,1,\ldots,1)$ in the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part ii, can you write down the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $B$? What do you know about the determinant of a diagonal matrix?

As for part iii, what do you not understand? If $T, F \in GL(V)$, with matrices $[T]_B, [F]_B \in GL(n, \mathbb R)$ respectively (wrt some fixed basis $B$), what is the matrix that represents $T \circ F$?

As for proving it's an isomorphism, you can either show one of subjectivity or injectivity and use a dimension argument, or argue it's bijective from the one-to-one correspondence between matrices and linear maps once a basis has been specified.